# How to reduce the droop

Tags: voltage

I am using LTspice to simulate a circuit that has a PWM driving a pulled-up sensor using a NPN BJT.

When the PWM truns off I see a droop of about .6Volt.

What's the best way to get rid of it? Should I use a capacitor in parallel to the BJT?

My circuit is:

```
                    +------/\/\/\/\------+
                    |                    |
  PWM source ------NPN                   +--- PWM consumer
                    |                    |
                    |                   12v
                    |                    |
                   GND                  GND
```

[image]

Comment: Try driving the base via a 10 k resistor.

Comment: That helped! Thanks a lot!

Comment: So, did you get what you want or is there room for further improvement do you think?

Comment: No, looks cool now. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> When the PWM truns off I see a droop of about .6Volt.

Try driving the base via a 10 k resistor.

> That helped! Thanks a lot! – LD1117

So, did you get what you want or is there room for further improvement do you think? – Andy aka

> No, looks cool now. Thanks a lot! – LD1117

The problem is that you were over driving the base and forward biasing the normally reverse biased collector and actually raising it from close to its conventional saturation level of a few tens of mV.